# Using jQuery trying to change background-color of text box but not working in wordpress

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

Here is jQuery code which I am using .

```
<input class="jscolor" name="jscolor" value="F078A0" />
<input name="my_txtbox" type="text" id="my_txtbox_id" value="F078A0" />

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('.jscolor').on('change', function($) {
    var color = jQuery('.jscolor').val();
    jQuery('#my_txtbox_id').text(color);
    jQuery('#my_txtbox_id').attr('value',color);
    jQuery('#my_txtbox_id').css('background-color',color);
});
</script>
```

I put this in my plugin function file `#my_txtbox_id` get value of color but `background-color` CSS is not working.

How to solve this?

Comment: What is element type of `#my_txtbox_id`?

Comment: <input type="text" id="my_txtbox_id">

Comment: Do you want to set text of one input to another?

Comment: Please show html code

Comment: No I am using jscolor picker in my plugin [link](http://jscolor.com/) you can see here I get value from it to `#my_txtbox_id` but `background-color` css is not changing.

Comment: you can see my full code in my question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The color code needs a prepending `#` to be used with CSS.

Change

```
jQuery('#my_txtbox_id').css('background-color',color);
```

To

```
jQuery('#my_txtbox_id').css('background-color', '#' + color);
```

Edit: You can further optimize the code like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.jscolor').on('change', function (e) {
        var color = $(this).val();
        $('#my_txtbox_id').val(color).css('background-color', '#' + color);
    });
});
```

Comment: Got what I wanted Thanks

Comment: Still when I update my post the value is same but `background-color` is changed again