# jscolor textbox background not changed while update from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jscolor

html content

```
<input type="text" id="menuBg" class="jscolor"  autocomplete="off" value="fff">
```

update textbox value from jquery

```
$('#menuBg').val('2AFF17');
```

[image]

the given value is updated in the text field but the background color does not getting updated.

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue in a code  snippet ?

Comment: What rule, either jQuery or CSS, is in your code that leads you to believe the background-colour should be updated?

Comment: Please check this link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37629690/using-jquery-trying-to-change-background-color-of-text-box-but-not-working-in-wo

Comment: thank you the issue resolved with the given link

Answer (score 1):

You should change the css color property as such:

```
$('#menuBg').css('background-color','#2AFF17');
```

Changing the val property only changes the content of the textfield.

Comment: this is not working.

Comment: I edited the answer